# What is this hash algorithm?

Tags: hash, base64, reverse-engineering, penetration-testing

Being a pentester, I have encountered a hash divided in two parts (the first one probably being the salt) seemingly encoded in Base64 but I am unable to find out the encryption type.

The input that gave me this hash is the string "password". Is anybody able to give me a hint ?

> `67Wm8zeMSS0=`
>
> `s9bD0QOa7A6THDMLa39+3LmXgcxzUFdmszeZdlTUzjY=`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's SHA-256 encoded (or any other 256 bit hash algorithm), because if you base64 decode it and hex encode you get:

> `ebb5a6f3378c492d`
>
> `b3d6c3d1039aec0e931c330b6b7f7edcb99781cc73505766b337997654d4ce36`

The first has an length of 16 and the second a length of 64. That's probably not a coincidence.

Edit: Maybe it's hashed multiple times; an iterated hash. As [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168077/how-find-the-hash-creation-method-knowing-password-salt-and-resulting-hash) post says it is better to decompile the software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will continue my researches, I still can't find out why "password" becomes  `b3d6c3d1039aec0e931c330b6b7f7edcb99781cc73505766b337997654d4ce36` or the way it is salted.

Comment: yeah I tried almost all combinations of `sha256($pass.$salt)`, `sha256($salt.$pass)` and `sha256($salt.$pass.$salt)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for trying though. But yes it's been a while I'm decompiling with Immunity & IDA but my Rev skills are still too low to identify the way it is hashed